# python3.x: display pdf in browser with cgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, cgi

I am upgrading some code from python2 to python3.  I have the following cgi script to display a pdf in the browser.  It works fine in python2, but doesn't work in python3.  In python 3, there is no server error, but rather I get an error from the browser which says "Failed to load PDF document."

I believe the problem has to do with the encoding, but I am at a loss after searching for a few hours.  The current CGI script is here:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

filename='file.pdf'
file = open(filename,'rb')
fileData=file.read()
file.close() 

print('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"')
print('Content-type: application/pdf')
print('')
print(fileData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

filename='file.pdf'
file = open(filename,'rb')
fileData=file.read()
file.close() 

print('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"')
print('Content-type: application/pdf')
print('')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.buffer.write(fileData)
```